# How can I use SQL to extract the details of any stored-procedure deployed as part of any given change?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, ssms

I'm looking to write a bit of code that I can use to gather what items were deployed as part of the same change.

At them moment, I am using the below code,

```
DECLARE @Package INT = (SELECT MAX(package_id) FROM SSISDB.catalog.packages WHERE [name] = 'MyPackage.dtsx')
SELECT  pr.project_id
,       pr.[name]
,       pr.last_deployed_time
,       pr.deployed_by_name
,       pa.[name]
,       pa.version_build
FROM SSISDB.catalog.projects pr
INNER JOIN SSISDB.catalog.packages pa ON pr.project_id = pa.project_id
WHERE   pa.package_id = @Package
```

This currently targeted to when a given SSIS packages was released, but sometimes I may have to check a solution that is only a stored procedure change, so no SSIS package).

Is there a way of getting stored procedure changes in a similar way via SQL?

Comment: SQL Server does not track detailed changes like that. All it tracks is `create_date` and `modified_date` in `sys.objects`. If you need more details, you can set up a DDL trigger (synchronous) or event notification (asynchronous) to record the changes yourself.

Comment: Your database schema and objects should be source-controlled like your code - that is where you track such things.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, this is for a tester to use, not a developer. Not every tester has access to the source code, or is confident enough to use GIT.
This would be used as part of a early live support test to evidence the new code is deployed, and is from a testing perspective.

Answer (score 1):

After some discussions with one of the developers, I have come to the following code, which although uses dynamic SQL, none of the testers have any permissions other than to tempdb, so will be safe for them to use.

```
DECLARE @DaysBack VARCHAR(2) = '-1'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#D') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #D;
CREATE TABLE #D (
    [DBName] [NVARCHAR](128) NULL,
    [SchemaName] [NVARCHAR](128) NULL,
    [name] [NVARCHAR](128) NOT NULL,
    [type_desc] [VARCHAR](30) NOT NULL,
    [create_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [modify_date] [datetime] NULL,
    )


SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) AS cnt
,       name
INTO    #T
FROM    sys.databases 
DECLARE @sqlVar INT = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM #T);
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);


WHILE @sqlVar > 0
BEGIN
    SET @DBName = (SELECT name FROM #T WHERE cnt = @sqlVar)
    SET @SQL = 
    'BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO #D
    SELECT  ''' + @DBName + ''' AS DBName 
    ,       schema_name(schema_id) AS SchemaName
    ,       [name]
    ,       [type_desc]
    ,       [create_date]
    ,       [modify_date]
    FROM    ' + @DBName + '.sys.objects
    WHERE   [modify_date] > DATEADD(dd,' + @DaysBack + ',GETDATE()) AND
        [type] NOT IN (''S'',''U'',''PK'',''D'',''V'',''FN'',''UQ'',''SQ'',''IT'',''F'',''TF'',''IF'',''TT'')
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH
    '
    --SELECT @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    SET @sqlVar = @sqlVar-1 
END

SELECT * FROM #D ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```